# Object Detection and Masking in Image

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, object-detection, image-masking

I want to do foreground extraction (object detection) in image, then apply mask on it.

currently I have done object detection with openCV, but now I am facing issue in Object masking.

My platform is android.

Comment: Can you add more information? E.g. your image and the code that you have written so far.

Comment: Yeah sure, here it is the example code which I am using
https://github.com/mrmitew/GrabCutAndroid